# DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated, where to find it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, deprecation-warning

So i keep getting this error which redirects me to node_modules and I'm not sure if I would check there.. Everything was fine until node.js version update yesterday.

The error with trace:

```
node --trace-deprecation tradeBot.js
        (node:10062) DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
        at maybeCallback (fs.js:95:42)
    at Object.fs.writeFile (fs.js:1191:14)
    at FileStorage.saveFile.FileStorage.writeFile (/****/node_modules/file-manager/index.js:68:5)
    at SteamUser._handlers.(anonymous function) (/****/node_modules/steam-user/components/logon.js:252:18)
    at SteamUser._handleMessage (/****/node_modules/steam-user/components/messages.js:200:29)
    at emitThree (events.js:116:13)
    at CMClient.emit (events.js:194:7)
    at CMClient._netMsgReceived (/****/node_modules/steam-client/lib/cm_client.js:278:8)
    at CMClient.handlers.(anonymous function) (/****/node_modules/steam-client/lib/cm_client.js:386:8)
    at CMClient._netMsgReceived (/****/node_modules/steam-client/lib/cm_client.js:260:24)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at TCPConnection.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at TCPConnection._readPacket (/****/node_modules/steam-client/lib/tcp_connection.js:73:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at TCPConnection.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:432:10)
```

Comment: What is `maybeCallback`?

Comment: `node_modules/file-manager/index.js line 68 column 5`? Report a bug with [the package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-manager).

Comment: @Bergi its says on that line `fs.writeFile(this.directory + '/' + filename, contents, callback);` what is the other option for that? instead of writeFile

Comment: OK, then apparently `callback` is `undefined`, and you need to check the call stack for where nothing is passed.

Comment: i tried to decrease node version to previous (6.9.1) with nvm but now even node script wont work

Comment: and how to check for the call stack @Bergi ?

Comment: I meant you need to check every line mentioned in the call stack and trace the origin of `callback` to see how it became `undefined`.

Comment: Ok but it seems that it comes undefined to file-manager